# I want to calculate the last 20 leap year for which I have written this code, can this code be further optimized

Tags: java, optimization

```
package javaHM;

import java.util.*;

public class LeapYear {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Starting Year");
        int year = obj.nextInt();
            leapFor(year);
            
        obj.close();

    }

    public static int leapFor(int year) {
        int counter = 0, i;
        for (i = year; i >= 1; i--) {
            if ((i % 4 == 0) && i % 100 != 0 || i % 400 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
                counter++;

            }
            if (counter == 20)
                break;
        }
        return i;

    }
}
```

I want to optimize this portion of code , please help me

Comment: can you create a code for me please

Comment: @rzwitserloot are you sure about that?

Comment: "can this code be further optimized" there is little point in looping in increments of 1. Go in increments of 4 (starting at `year / 4 * 4`).

Comment: can you create a code for me

Comment: why do you feel this needs optimising? Are you optimising for speed, readability, or coursework marks? @AndyTurner has already suggested the best optimisation. You could also ascertain outside the loop if the previous 20 leap years skip over a non-leap-year century. Also, the rules for historic leap years change from country to country as different countries adopted the Gregorian calendar at different times.

Comment: I would just use the static method `Year.isLeap()` from the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.  And it would simplify your code.

Comment: @rzwitserloot ok I'm checking Wikipedia. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000 *2000 (MM) was a century **leap year** starting on Saturday of the Gregorian calendar, the 2000th year of the Common Era (CE) and Anno Domini (AD) designations, the 1000th and last year of the 2nd millennium, the 100th and last year of the 20th century, and the 1st year of the 2000s decade.*

Comment: @rzwitserloot  You are incorrect.  Century years that are divisible by 400 are leap years.  2100 is divisible by 4 but is not a leap year because it is not divisible by 400.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function does I/O on every iteration. I/O is slow, so the optimization with the biggest effect is accumulating the output into a buffer, and printing it only once. Any changes to the arithmetic will not make a meaningful difference.

```
public static int leapFor(int year) {
    int counter = 0, i;
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(20*(4+1));
    for (i = year; i >= 1; i--) {
        if ((i % 4 == 0) && i % 100 != 0 || i % 400 == 0) {
            output.append(i).append('\n');
            counter++;

        }
        if (counter == 20)
            break;
    }
    System.out.print(output);
    return i;
}
```